# commenting module by ajax not working in laravel 5

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel-5

i am working on commenting module in my project by ajax. i am getting this error

```
 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and the data not post. what i am doing wrong? My route is a resource route and i want to display it without refreshing the page .

**Form**

```
<form action="{{route('comments.store')}}" method="post">
   {{  csrf_field() }}
   <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
      <div class="form-group">
          <textarea name="comment-msg" id="comment-name" cols="30" rows="1" class="form-control" placeholder="comment here..."></textarea>
          <input  type="hidden" id="eventID" name="eventID" value="<?php echo $eventData->id; ?>">
          <input  type="hidden" id="userID" name="userID" value="<?php echo Auth::user()->id; ?>">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <button type="submit" id="submit-comment" class="btn-primary pull-right">Comment</button>
    </div>
   </form>
```

**Ajax Call**

```js
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')}
    });

        $( '#submit-comment' ).click(function() {
            var formData = {
                'message'              : $('#comment-msg').val(),
                'eventID'             : $('#eventID').val(),
                'userID'             : $('#userID').val(),
            };


            $.ajax({
                        type        : 'POST',
                        url         : '{{route('comments.store')}}',
                        data        : formData,
                        dataType    : 'json', 
                        encode          : true,
                        success: function (response) {
                          console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                            alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
                        }
                    });
            event.preventDefault();
        } );
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $content = $request->input( 'comment-msg' );
        $userID = $request->input( 'userID' );
        $eventID = $request->input( 'eventID' );

    $response=Comment::create([

        'user_id'  =>  $userID,
        'event_id'  =>  $eventID,
        'message'  =>  $content,
    ]);
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');
```

Comment: checked your routes? what is in the logs??

Comment: @OmarElDon i edit it and mention the route .. please check it and tell me what u mean by logs??

Comment: the logs, the error reports

Comment: what error do you get in the console log of your browser

Comment: the data not return in console log but under the internal Server Error the following error
   ` send @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ 138?_token=YikOy0Gou6ZsKUGkoMG7sWjMqevqcbAj9FrUG4x6&comment-msg=dfsfasfda&eventID=138&userID=33:764
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3 `

Comment: not in the v8 console but on the server

Comment: no error occur on the browser.. but the error function of the ajax call

Comment: @JamalAhmad there are many mistakes in your code, i'll try to correct them all n one answer hoping it helps

Comment: try `url   : '{{route("comments.store")}}'` instead of `url  : '{{route('comments.store')}}'`

Comment: @AmrAly yes but i am getting this
 `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments".
JSON Formatter: Type "json" to inspect.`

Comment: try to copy paste my answer

Comment: keep my code for clearness... and try to locate your server's error logging files... there you'll have your answers